# How to add class in a common Header component based on the redux data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react JS application, I have a notification icon added in header component. I have created a separate component where I am doing api calls to get the data and display it. what I am trying to achieve here is to change the color of the icon in a Header component if there is some notification alerts.
My Header component-

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  setPoiData,
  getNotification,
  updateNotification
} from "../../actions/action";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const axios = require("axios");

    class Notification extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const data = this.props.getNotificationStatus;
        const highlightBellIcon = Object.keys((data.length === 0))



          return (
              <div className="notification-parent">

                <Link to="/notification-details">
                  <span className={"glyphicon glyphicon-bell " + (!highlightBellIcon ? 'classA' : 'classB')} />
                </Link>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
        const mapStateToProps = state => ({
          getNotificationStatus: state.root.getNotificationStatus
        });

        export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Notification)
```

Here, getNotificationStatus is the state that holds the value in Redux.

Notification-details Component-

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getNotification
} from "../../actions/action";
import { Spinner } from "../Spinner";
import { setTimeout } from "timers";
import NotificationTile from "../NotificationTile/NotificationTile";

const axios = require("axios");
class NotificationDetails extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.handleNotification(), 2000);
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        }),
      10000
    );
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  };
  handleNotification = () => {
    let postData = {
       //inputParams
    }
    //call to action
    this.props.dispatch(getNotification(postData));
  };

  getNotificationDetails = data => {
    const payloadData =
      data.payLoad &&
      data.payLoad.map(item => {
        console.log(this);
        return <NotificationTile {...item} history={this.props.history} />;
      });
    //console.log(payloadData);
    return payloadData;
    console.log("InitialState" + payloadData);
  };
  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;
    const data = this.props.getNotificationStatus;
    return (
      <div className="notificationContainer container">
        <div className="notification-alert">
          {!loading ? (
            this.getNotificationDetails(data)
          ) : (
            <h1>
              Waiting for notifications..
              <Spinner />
            </h1>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getNotificationStatus: state.root.getNotificationStatus
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotificationDetails);
```

The problem I am facing is always classB is getting added since the api call happens on click of the bell icon. So when I land to the page first time, api call doesn't happen unless I click on the bell icon. My code is absolutely working fine, It is just that I need to add the class to my Notification component (which is a global component) based on the response received in NotificationDetail Comp which is a sibling comp.Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where is dispatch, I mean mapDispatchToProps? and where is your API call? I can't see that in code.

Comment: api call I am doing in another component. Is there any way I can read that response in header?

Comment: You are importing NotificationDetails but I don't see you using it, where are you using it?

Comment: I am not using it. Removed it from code. Have added it before but there was no need to use as child comp so have removed.

Comment: notification-details is the component where you get the data right?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G, correct.

Comment: Please find I have answered below.

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G I have updated my answer. Everything is absolutely working fine. I only want to change the color of the Bell icon in the Notification component based on the response in Notification-detail comp

Answer (score 0):

When you have to update your REDUX store, based on an Asynchronous call, you should be using something called **Action Creators**, These action creators will give you the ability 
to dispatch an action after your response from you async call.

Use [Redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

In this below code **setTimeout** is where your async call goes in

```
const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';

function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}

function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

Update you **REDUX Store** and you call this action creator from **componentDidMount()**
so that you get your notifications the very first time.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing but in a component which appears on click of the notification bell. The challenge I am facing is to update the icon based on the notification component response. In my case, I am doing an api call, every 10 sec in a component that loads on click of the bell icon.

Answer (score 0):

`notification-details` is a separate component which fetches the data and adds it to store and
there is  `<Link to="/notification-details">` which loads this component, in this case, your store
initially will not have data until you click on the bell icon, which is correct behavior.

**Solution:**

Please go one step up in your component tree, I mean go to a component which is superior to
Notification ( its Container component ), and load **notification-details** in there ( you can use any creational lifecycle hook),
,also have a flag ( something like **isNotificationLoaded** ) which checks where **state.root.getNotificationStatus** 
is filled with data and load the Notification panel only after that is true.

something like

```
render() {
 const data = this.props.getNotificationStatus;
 const noticationPanel = data.length > 0 ? <Notification/> : null;

 return({noticationPanel});
}
```

This will make sure  loads only when there is data, until then 
you can show some activity indicator.

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: I did not get this - "Please go one step up in your component tree, I mean go to a component which is superior to Notification ( its Container component )" I have kept it in a header component which has no parent. I can only have it in app.js

Comment: I would advise to have it in app.js first and see if this approach works, I am sure it will work

Comment: I am not really sure if this will help as having the data in a parent component will intern trigger the api call and the divs will start getting rendered. Instead, I just want to dispatch or pass the data in such a way that I can reuse the existing component logic.

Comment: Ok, I understand, can I see how your notification-details component looks like, can you add that code?

Comment: sure, let me edit my Question and add notification-details